# How to use the same auth userprofile in multiple apps in Django 1.6

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm using Django 1.6 auth module to login users and I have a project consisting of two apps and I want to use the same user by calling request.user.username in the view in my second app. That is, in my template login.html in the first app this works {% if user.is_authenticated %} but {% if user.is_authenticated %} does not work in the second apps templates and I'm wondering how I can fetch it in functions in the second app? I've tried to fetch it with user=request.user.username but it doesn't work.

In my first app:

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Userprofile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 70)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class OneUser(models.Model):

    Firstname = models.CharField(max_length = 35)
    Lastname = models.CharField(max_length = 35)
    Email = models.EmailField()
    belongsTo = models.ForeignKey(Userprofile, related_name='pcslabeler_userprofile')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Firstname
```

in views.py

```
def LoginIndex(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render(request,"login.html", c)

    #logins = Login.objects.all()


def one_login(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)# user firstname lastname


    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/loggedin')# topic
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/invalid')




def loggedin(request):
    return render(request,"loggedin.html",{'full_name': request.user.username})

def invalid_login(request):
    return render(request,"invalid_login.html")

def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return render(request,"logout.html")
```

In the second apps view I'm trying to use it in the function postoneEval:

```
def EvalIndex(request):
    evals = Evaluation.objects.all()

    return render_to_response("evaluation_index.html",{"evals":evals})

def one_evaluation(request, postID):

    one_eval = Evaluation.objects.get(id=postID)
    one_part = Participation.objects.get(id=postID)


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EvalForm(request.POST)
        form2 = ParticipationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            postoneEval(request, one_eval)
            postoneParticipant(request, one_part)

    else:
        form = EvalForm()
        form2 = ParticipationForm()


    c = {"one_eval":one_eval,"one_part":one_part, "form":form, "form2":form2}
    c.update(csrf(request))


    return render_to_response("one_evaluation_index.html", c )


def postoneEval(request, one_eval):

    title = request.POST["title"]

    user = request.user.username

    oneEval = OneEvaluation(datetime=datetime.datetime.now(), belongsTo=one_eval, title=title, user=user)

    oneEval.save()
```

Comment: Show the view code of the second app, please.

Comment: I've added the function in the second apps view where I'm using request.user.username to fetch the same user that is instantiated in the first app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `render_to_reponse()` call.  You do not pass the `RequesContext` instance so context processors aren't run for your templates.

The simplest solution for this issue is to replace the `render_to_response()` with the `render()`:

```
return render(request, "evaluation_index.html", {"evals":evals})
```

and:

```
return render(request, "one_evaluation_index.html", c)
```